# Constrain Type to Any Instance of Generic Type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a base entity that I can use with multiple data access systems. The generic type argument represents the type of a property.

```
public interface IEntity<T> {
    public T Id {get; set;}
}
```

I want to be able to use this interface as a generic type constraint without having to specify a type parameter in a generic method.

```
public void Read<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : IEntity<**any type**>
```

Is this possible? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this.  Add a second generic type parameter:

```
public void Read<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : IEntity<U>
```

Comment: Note (not a criticism of the answer) that you must still define `U` when calling the method, ie: `Read<Person, int>(a => true);` assuming `Person : IEntity<int>`

Answer (score 2):

Use a constraint on that type parameter and specify both types in the declare. This pushes the decision about what TOther is down the chain.

```
public void Read<T,TOther>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : IEntity<TOther>
```